# after o before no muestra imagen en local

Tags: css3, css-grid-layout

hola estoy armando una pagina simple usando la grid de css por primera vez, y cuando quise colocar una imagen con :before no me la toma indicando la ruta de la donde esta ubicada: "imagenes/icono.png"... estuve viendo la bibliográfica sobre el tema y no encuentro que puede ser.
paso código para ver si pueden orientarme

```css
.contenedor #contacto {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.65em;
}

.contenedor #contacto #maipu .sede {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #48887b;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}


/*elementos de cada sede*/

.contenedor #contacto #maipu .dir {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*datos de cada sede*/

.contenedor #contacto #maipu .dir h3 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: -1;
  position: relative;
}

.contenedor #contacto #maipu .dir h3::before {
  content: url(http://ibemo.es/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/ubi-300x268.png);
  position: absolute;
  top:-100px;
  left:-200px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

.contenedor #contacto #maipu{
  padding: 10px 10px;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div id="contacto">
    <div id="maipu">
      <h3 class="sede">MAIPÚ</h3>
      <div class="dir">
        <h3>Ozamis 309</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Es solo una fracción del código para que vean como lo estoy planteando.
Tengo dos problemas
1) no me toma la imagen desde la carpeta pero si la muestra cuando es una imagen de internet (con ruta http://....)
2) cuando toma la imagen me deja posicionarla pero no modificar las medidas

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Todas tus reglas **CSS** hacen referencia a un elemento `.contenedor` que en tu **HTML** no existe, por lo que ninguna de ellas te va a funcionar. Prueba a quitarlo y verás como cambia la cosa ^^

Comment: me comi esa parte del codigo, pero en el archivo si existe (jajaj) ahi lo corregi en la pregunta y si funciona, asi que debo tener el error en otra parte superior del codigo. Lo reviso y si no encuentro el error lo planteo nuevamente. gracias

Comment: @phpMyGuel ahi modifique la pregunta xq descubri que el problema lo tengo con imagenes en local pero no con las de internet

Comment: En referencia a las imágenes que no se muestran, si no es problema de rutas debe de ser de permisos. Yo verificaría lo que nos cuenta nuestra amiga la consola de desarrollador del navegador, normalmente nos da pistas clave. En cuanto a lo de que no te funcione el alterarle las medidas es normal, no está permitido. No obstante existe un pequeño truco para conseguirlo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/298155/dar-tama%c3%b1o-a-imagen-de-uncontent-en-css/298163#298163

Comment: @phpMyGuel gracias por el aporte, use el background-image para darle tamaño y funciono perfecto pero sigue sin mostrar la imagen... lo subi completo al codigo para que lo puedas ver mejor, xq la consola me muestra (por lo poco que entiendo) que esta la imagen (me la muestra como respuesta al chequear que existe la ruta) pero despues mas abajo me dice "not found" cuando hace el llamado del selector... te paso el enlace para que puedas ve la consola:  https://timondigital.com/pruebas/proximamente.html 
gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es de rutas relativas, y de como estás funcionan.

Por un lado tienes la etiqueta:

`<img src="imagenes/ubicacion.png" alt="icono de ubicacion">`

Y por otro tienes la regla **CSS**:

```
.contenedor #contacto #maipu .dir h3::before {
    background-image: url(imagenes/ubicacion.png);
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    top: -5px;
    left: -25px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comenzaremos por el caso de la etiqueta. El attributo `src` de tu imagen usa la ruta relativa `imagenes/ubicacion.png`, lo que significa que el navegador va a localizar el sitio desde donde se llama a esta ruta (la ubicación de tu archivo **HTML** ya que la ruta está en una etiqueta impresa en este), va a buscar una carpeta *imagenes* y ahí dentro va a busca la imagen llamada *ubicacion.png*.

La ruta absoluta correspondiente, a esto sería:

**https://timondigital.com/pruebas/imagenes/ubicacion.png**

Ruta que es encontrada perfectamente por el navegador.

Ahora revisemos el segundo caso. Partimos del lugar donde está ubicado este **CSS** y llamamos a la ruta `imagenes/ubicacion.png`. Pero he aquí el problema, tu archivo **CSS** no se encuentra en el mismo directorio que tu **HTML**, por lo que si el punto de partida de la ruta cambia, ¿no debería hacerlo también la ruta relativa para alcanzar el destino?

La ruta absoluta desde tu **CSS** queda así:

**https://timondigital.com/pruebas/css/imagenes/ubicacion.png**

Y como esta ruta no existe en tu sistema de directorios te devuelve un **404**.

**Solución:**

Lo que yo haría sería cambiar tus rutas relativas para que comiencen buscando desde la raíz y una vez allí ya se busque la ruta que te interesa.

**HTML**

```
<img src="/pruebas/imagenes/ubicacion.png" alt="icono de ubicacion">
```

**CSS**

```
.contenedor #contacto #maipu .dir h3::before {
    background-image: url(/pruebas/imagenes/ubicacion.png);
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    top: -5px;
    left: -25px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

De esa manera puedes usar la misma ruta independientemente de desde donde se llame dentro de tu sistema de directorios.

Comment: perfecta tu explicación! ahora entendí clarisimo la respuesta que me tiraba la consola.
La imagen en el HTML esta porque estaba probando otra forma de solucionarlo sin el after (pero me estaba complicando la existencia hacerlo así)
Error de principiante el mio de no "salir" de la carpeta css ( ../ ) antes de entrar en la de imágenes cuando cargue la ruta
Funciono con esa corrección, mil gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios errores en los selectores.

El primero es que en el CSS haces referencia a un elemento con clase `.contenedor` mientras que en el HTML el elemento que más se parece tiene clase `.contenedor2`.

Por otra parte, tal y como tú lo estás poniendo estás indicando que debe actuar sobre un elemento con `id=contacto` dentro de un elemento con `class=contenedor`, y debería ser un elemento que contenga dicho id y clase.

El selector debería ser ambos juntos: `#contacto.contenedor2`, sin espacios entre ellos. De esta manera le estás diciendo que es un elemento con dicho id y dicha clase.

Corrigiendo esto se te quedaría de la siguiente forma y funcionaría perfectamente:

```css
#contacto.contenedor2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.65em;
}

#contacto.contenedor2 .sede {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #48887b;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

/*elementos de cada sede*/

#contacto.contenedor2 .dir {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*datos de cada sede*/

#contacto.contenedor2 .dir h3 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: -1;
}

#contacto.contenedor2 .dir h3::before {
  content: url(http://ibemo.es/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/ubi-300x268.png);
  position: absolute;
}

#contacto.contenedor2 #maipu {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}
```

```html
<div id="contacto" class="contenedor2">
  <div id="maipu">
    <h3 class="sede">MAIPÚ</h3>
    <div class="dir">
      <h3>Ozamis 309</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por el aporte, chequeo lo que me comentas y te cuento como me fue.

Comment: ahi modifique la pregunta xq descubri que el problema lo tengo con imagenes en local pero no con las de internet (ya controle la ruta y no es el problema)